# scroll down to document height but + 100

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this script

```
$("body, html").animate({scrollTop: $(document).height()}, 1000)
```

As seen above it will make so the the page is scrolled down to the documents height: aka the bottom.
However in my case its too far down, I would like to scroll down to `bottom:100px;` or `bottom:10%;` 
Is this possible? I found [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13237555/jquery-load-content-when-scroll-to-bottom-100px-of-page-multiple-events-fired) but [they](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6219570/do-something-100px-before-the-scrollbar-reaches-bottom/6219605) didn't work for me.
What am I missing to make it work?:)

Comment: Hi Jack. So if you try `scrollTop: $(document).height() - 100` it doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can set the value of scrollTop to any value you can mathematically calculate:

```
// Top is 100 px short of bottom
$("body, html").animate({scrollTop: $(document).height() - 100}, 1000)
```

```
// 90% scroll down
$("body, html").animate({scrollTop: $(document).height() * 0.9}, 1000)
```

Note that for all these, 100px is ***very small***. Your browser window would have to be <100px tall for it to NOT scroll all the way to the bottom.

You can use the visible height of the browser window in your equation too:

```
$(window).height()
```

Comment: Thanks for your explenation since I was already scrolled down a bit the - 100px of height was always scrolling to the bottom, but now I understand